# US Hospitals by Number of Beds

Tags: medical

Where can one find a list of all US hospitals with the number of licensed beds?  I believe that CMS provides this data somewhere, but I cannot find it!

Comment: Found [an expensive dataset](https://www.ahadataviewer.com/quickreport/), but no open one yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you are looking for the medicare cost reports

https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Downloadable-Public-Use-Files/Cost-Reports/Hospital-2010-form.html

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of beds per hospital '*non-federal, short-term, acute care hospitals*', ordered by state, so in 50 clicks you'll have the data: https://www.ahd.com/state_statistics.html

I strongly suspect that this list is incomplete, and some hospitals have reported 0 beds, which seems unlikely.

Also contains number of discharges, patient days and gross revenue.